# Someone help me with error propagation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, error-propagation

I have a fraction: $y = (A/B)-1$, where $A$ and $B$ are values (constants) with an associate value of error. How do I calculate the error of each $y$?

And then I have to plot the average value of my matrix with these many $y$. What do I do with the errors in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: At the very least, you will need to explain how your matrix might be related to "these many y" and what you mean by the "average value" of a matrix.  Assuming the errors are relatively small, your first question is answered in several threads here on CV: search our site for "delta method."

Comment: I calculate each y = (A/B)-1 and put the result on a matrix, that's what I mean. And then have to calculate mean(matrix_y)

Comment: OK, but what is the relevance of putting these into a matrix when all you're doing is averaging them?  BTW, this search turns up some useful looking answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22delta%20method%22%20ratio%20-odds%20score%3a1

Comment: When I do the mean of my several y, it is statistically correct to just do the mean of the errors too?

Comment: Well--no.  It would help for you to edit your post to emphasize that this is your main question.